# migrate spring oauth db from inmemory to jdbc

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, oauth

I'm trying to add oauth2 support to my java rest service,

i have manged to get it work in memory:

```
protected static class MyAuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter extends
            AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
...
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
            .inMemory()
                .withClient("myapp")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .authorities("USER")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .secret("mysecret");
        }
...
    }
```

the problem, every time the server restart the db is lost.
so i would like to connect it and existing standalone SQL db, any idea or guide how it can be done?

i found that there is a jdbc option, but i cant find a way to make it work

```
clients.jdbc(dataSource)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you want to put the client configuration in the database? This would only allow you to configure new clients dynamically.

What I think you want is have your tokens saved in the database so if you restart your server the client will not lose their session.

This can be made with the following code:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception }
    endpoints.tokenStore(new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource)).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

Here is the code to create the database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `oauth_access_token` (
  `token_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `token` blob,
  `authentication_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authentication` blob,
  `refresh_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `oauth_refresh_token` (
  `token_id` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `token` blob,
  `authentication` blob
);
```

Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql

Comment: i would like to put the token in the db as well, but it will be the next step, putting both of them will be better